# error in update with composer in ezlatform 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, ezplatform

i'm using ezplatform 5.4  , and when i run composer update/install , it show me this error :

```
[ErrorException]                                                                                     
 Declaration of 
 eZ\Bundle\EzPublishLegacyBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets() 
should be compatible with 
Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets
(Composer\Script\Event $event)
```

i don't find any response to get out from this error , and i hope some solution for that .

thank you in advance .

Comment: This is a bug in this 'ezplatform' software. Bring it up with them.

Comment: Yep, sounds like a bug with ezPlatform. In the meantime you can at least install the dependencies using composer with --no-scripts option: `composer install --no-scripts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution bundle required in the root composer.json must be updated. On the [5.4.x update instructions](https://doc.ez.no/display/EZP/5.4.x+Update+Instructions#id-5.4.xUpdateInstructions-From5.4.2andlower) page for eZ Platform, you will see for version 5.4.2 that it must be bumped to ~3.0.

Running the composer require command from this chapter may therefore fix your error, but it is hard to be 100% sure. Let me know.